# iOS Objective C- related to UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

In My ViewController.h i have Two UIView XIB's XIB-A & XIB-B and I have a Button on UIView XIB-A, Iam Trying to invoke that Button Action But I doen't Responding to that IBAction....

Help Me out with this issue

Comment: xib associated with its class files ?

Comment: you have to set the target to the class in which its defined not self. show some code. then can help u

Comment: Are you seeing any filled circle on left side of button IBaction?

Comment: i used  "HHHorizontalPagingView.h" API for Collapse Action

Comment: button action where declared ?

Comment: at View XIB-A i declared that Buttton Action

Answer (score 0):

Try linking your view to your class file like this:

[image]